# Java substring with one char

Tags: java, substring

I have

```
String x = g.substring(0, 1);
if (x == "S") {
    stuff
}
```

I have a string, "Safety", but "stuff" doesn't run and my watch say x value = S and `x=="S"` = false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==` is used for `identity` comparison, and it checks whether the two `reference` points to the same object (in your case the object is `String`).

You should use the `equals` method to compare the contents of your string:

```
if (x.equals("S"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This compares references not string equality `x=="S"` you should use `"S".equals(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals()` method of String class instead, not `==`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x.equals("S"))
```

== checks the reference and not the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `String.equals` for comparing string content. The `==` operator is used for comparing object references.

Switching the positions of the arguments will avoid a `NullPointerException`:

```
if ("S".equals(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.equals` method to compare Strings (and any non-primitives in general).

```
if (x.equals("S")) {
    //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java `equals()` checks equality and `==` checks identity.

Answer (score 0):

Many problems...

- Your variable `x` is a `String`! You shouldn't use `==` operator with that, use `.equals()` instead
- Also, while you're at it, you should use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` to ignore case.
- By the way, I should note that there is the [String.charAt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) function too, which returns the character at the specified place...

But if you would like to select all Strings (your question didn't reveal your original intentions why and what you are trying to achieve), but I'd look into regular expressions, and using [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `charAt` function and do it like this:

```
    char x = g.charAt(0);
    if (x == 'S') {
       // Stuff
    }
```

If you don't want to use char, use the `equals` method in the `if` block comparison as:

```
   String x = g.substring(0, 1);
   if (x.equals("S")) {
      // stuff
   }
```